# Finding an element in a shared_ptr container?

Tags: c++, pointers, containers

I'm having a little problem with finding an element in a vector of `shared_ptr`.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Block>> blocks;

bool contains(Block* block) {
  for (auto i = blocks.begin(); i != blocks.end(); ++i) {
    if ((*i).get() == block) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

However, I didn't managed to do it with `std::find` or even `std::find_if`. Is there a more c++ compliant way to achieve this ?

**EDIT**: This is the code I have after the answer:

```
bool contains(Block* block) {
  auto found = std::find_if(blocks.begin(), blocks.end(), [block](std::shared_ptr<Block> const& i){
    return i.get() == block;
  });
  return found != blocks.end();
}
```

Comment: So you are looking for a `shared_ptr` to a specific _raw pointer_?

Comment: As a side note, if you need to find elements in your container then vector<> shouldn't be your container of choice. You will get much better performance with an ordered (sorted) container

Comment: Yes, `std::set` comes to mind.

Comment: @K-ballo I've used something like this before. For example, if I have a class that wants to check if it is inside of a vector, it only has a raw pointer to itself (`this`). Not a great thing to do, but can be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
std::find_if(blocks.begin(), blocks.end(), 
  [block](std::shared_ptr<Block> const& i){ return i.get() == block; });
```

Comment: You need to check if that isn't `blocks.end()`, to see if it is in the vector.

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler:

```
bool contains(Block* block) {
  return std::any_of(blocks.cbegin(), blocks.cend(),
                     [block](std::shared_ptr<Block> const& i) { return i.get() == block; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answers and comments from others, here is a fully working sample from [ideone](http://ideone.com/Ve9EqA):

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Block
{
    bool in_container(const vector<shared_ptr<Block>>& blocks)
    {
        auto end = blocks.end();
        return end != find_if(blocks.begin(), end,
                              [this](shared_ptr<Block> const& i)
                                  { return i.get() == this; });
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto block1 = make_shared<Block>();
    auto block2 = make_shared<Block>();

    vector<shared_ptr<Block>> blocks;
    blocks.push_back(block1);

    block1->in_container(blocks) ?
        cout << "block1 is in the container\n" :
        cout << "block1 is not in the container\n";

    block2->in_container(blocks) ?
        cout << "block2 is in the container\n" :
        cout << "block2 is not in the container\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
block1 is in the container
block2 is not in the container
```

Comment: No problem. I see that you came to an answer independently as well.